# Why my C++ program crash in release mode when a struct has default constructors?

Tags: c++, crash

Environment:
- GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 and Mageia 5)
- GCC 4.9.2 (under Mageia)
- System Qt5 and boost

Up to recently my program was working with no problem in debug and release mode. Unrelated changes (and not well identified) made it crash, but only in release mode. Not in debug.

In debug, valgrind does not signal any error. In release, It reports the use of non-initialized data but at the beginning of a method. By systematic search, I was able to track down to the use of the following struct:

```
struct LIMA_LINGUISTICANALYSISSTRUCTURE_EXPORT LinguisticElement {
  StringsPoolIndex inflectedForm;
  StringsPoolIndex lemma;
  StringsPoolIndex normalizedForm;
  LinguisticCode properties;
  MorphoSyntacticType type;
  bool operator==(const LinguisticElement& le) const;
  bool operator<(const LinguisticElement& le) const;
};
```

StringsPoolIndex and LinguisticCode are defined as:

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(uint64_t, StringsPoolIndex);
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(uint32_t, LinguisticCode);
```

and MorphoSyntacticType is an enum.

If I add explicit constructors and an operator=, the crash disappear and valgrind stops to signal errors.

```
LinguisticElement::LinguisticElement() :
  inflectedForm(0),
  lemma(0),
  normalizedForm(0),
  properties(0),
  type(NO_MORPHOSYNTACTICTYPE)

{
}
LinguisticElement::LinguisticElement(const  LinguisticElement& le) :
  inflectedForm(le.inflectedForm),
  lemma(le.lemma),
  normalizedForm(le.normalizedForm),
  properties(le.properties),
  type(le.type)
{
}
LinguisticElement& LinguisticElement::operator=(const LinguisticElement& le)
{
  inflectedForm = le.inflectedForm;
  lemma = le.lemma;
  normalizedForm = le.normalizedForm;
  properties = le.properties;
  type = le.type;
  return *this;
}
```

I don't understand why this can happen as my implementation is the same as what the compiler-generated one is, if I understand well. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Release and debug mode differ in compiler optimization. Disable optimization in release mode and try again.

Comment: The compiler-generated constructor does not initialize the structure members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `StringsPoolIndex` and `LinguisticCode` as fixed width integer types. As such, they will not be initialized by the compiler-synthesized constructor for your struct. Variables are often null initialized in debug mode (or to some specific value rare that rarely occurs), whereas the same does not happen in release mode unless explicitly stated. This is why you were experiencing the crash only in release build configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I was convinced that members with buit-in types were always null initialized in compiler-synthesized constructors ! I will have to check all my code…